# F1- OPT - Resident Alien - Social Security and Medicare taxes in the USA

Tags: united-states, income-tax, social-security, medicare

Please don't confuse it with answer [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/87691/do-i-have-to-pay-medicare-and-social-security-taxes-if-i-just-have-a-work-permit/87700#87700). Mine is not a duplicate question.

If I am on F1 (non-immigrant student) visa and doing my [OPT](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-opt-for-f-1-students) (1st year not the STEM extension) or I am a full time student (still on F1 visa) and have acquired the resident alien status for the tax purposes. Do I have to pay the social security and medicare taxes? I am a bit confused. Based on the screenshot pasted below from [this](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-student-liability-for-social-security-and-medicare-taxes) IRS page, I think I don't need to pay. However, [this](https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/taxes/discussion/re-international-citizen-resident-alien-f1-opt-social-security-and-medicare-tax/01/1983578/highlight/true#M714295) answer on turbotax says that I need to. Please advice.

[image: Screenshot from a IRS page]

Comment: You really need to explain what you mean by F1-OPT and so on.  FWIW (going the other direction, as a US citizen working in another country), the taxes are collected and applied to your home country's equivalent of Social Security.  But this depends on there being a treaty between the US and your country.

Comment: F1 --> is a visa type. It is non-immigrant student visa.
OPT --> Optional practical training. It is an option for International students to work as fulltime professional for a year in the US as part of their education. The following link has detailed description of it.
https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-opt-for-f-1-students

Comment: Actually, the IRS page you linked to says: "The exemption does not apply to F-1,J-1,M-1, or Q-1/Q-2 nonimmigrants who become resident aliens."

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on campus in the school where you are studying, you are exempt from FICA on that work even if you are a resident alien or US citizen. See [this page](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/student-exception-to-fica-tax) for more details.

If you are working on OPT, you are probably working off-campus, so this exception wouldn't apply. Also, if you are working full-time, the exception doesn't apply. So I think you have to pay FICA taxes if you are a resident alien.

Comment: Thanks. What if I am on OPT and working in a company as full time employee?

Comment: @PHcoDer: I updated

Comment: Thanks. I have confirmed from other sources too and it is correct what you said.